# Does there exist an irrational $a$ greater than $1$ such that $n|\lfloor{na^n}\rfloor$ for all natural $n$

Tags: number-theory

Does there exist an irrational number  $a$ greater than $1$ such that $n|\lfloor{na^n}\rfloor$ for all natural $n$?

**I guess we need to explicitly construct such an irrational ***

Comment: Sorry but how does it help in this one

Comment: So you've changed your question. Why do you think there is such an irrational? And why do you think we should find it for you?

Comment: We can make this work for all **odd** $n$ by taking $a=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$

Comment: Sorry mr professor vector I didn't change my question statement it is as it was I only edited the bold part which didn't have the question statement and sorry  if my choice of words was rude to you

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen We could have $n|\lceil n\,a^n\rceil,$ for all $n\ge1,$ with $a=3+2\sqrt2,$ say.